# Converting this conditional formatting to c#

Tags: c#, excel, conditional-formatting

I need to convert this exact conditional formatting to c#.

[image]

I tried using the below code. But as C5 is not in the range, it is not working.

```
Range extendedRange = activeWorksheet.get_Range("D5", oOpt).get_Resize(129, 3);
FormatConditions fcs = extendedRange.FormatConditions;
    FormatCondition fc = (FormatCondition)fcs.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreater, "=C5", oOpt, oOpt,
                                               oOpt, oOpt, oOpt);

                Interior interior = fc.Interior;
                interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
```

I am using interop.excel 12.0.0.0 . Could somebody help me out on how to fix this?. Thanks in advance

Edit:
I want this to be a realtive reference. So, What ever thats shown in the excel conditional formatting is precisely what i wanted. But , when i tried with my code the formula is changing to D5 instead of C5. I thought it could possibly because my range doesnt have C5 cell in it. I am using visual studio 2008 SP1.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. Is it giving you an error message?

A possible cause may be that you are using relative cell references and not absolute references.

With relative references, the formula you enter is applied to the first cell of the selection (typically the top left cell). Then for each further cell in the range to apply to, the cell reference is modified. So if the formula refers to the cell to the left of the first cell in the range to be highlighted then it will refer to the cell to the left of each cell to be highlighted.

With absolute references, the formula you enter will be applied exactly as you type it.

**For Example**

**With relative reference (Cell Value > C5 Applied to D5:F133)**

Basically, what you have is saying for every cell you want to highlight (e.g. D5:F133) if this value is greater than the cell directly to my left then highlight.

Thus to determine the following cells:

- Check D5 against C5
- Check D6 against C6
- Check D7 against C7
- Check E5 against D5
- Check E6 against D6
- And so on....

**With absolute reference (Cell Value > $C$5 applied to D5:F133)**

The condition will say, for every cell that you want to highlight, if this value is greater than the value in cell A1 then highlight.

Thus to determine the following cells:

- Check D5 against C5
- Check D6 against C5
- Check D7 against C5
- Check E5 against C5
- Check E6 against C5
- And so on....

To change your code to use absolute references you would simply add dollar signs ($) to the cell address you want, thus:

```
Range extendedRange = activeWorksheet.get_Range("D5", oOpt).get_Resize(129, 3);
FormatConditions fcs = extendedRange.FormatConditions;
FormatCondition fc = (FormatCondition)fcs.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
    XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreater,
    "=$C$5",
    oOpt,
    oOpt,
    oOpt,
    oOpt,
    oOpt);

Interior interior = fc.Interior;
interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
```

Notice the $ signs added to `"=$C$5"`

If this doesn't help you may need to explain better what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want this to be relative reference. When i execute the code , the formula is changing to D5 instead of C5. I thought its because i am applying on a range that doesnt have C5 in it. I am using visual studio 2008 SP1. Could that be a problem?.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be changing the cell formula. The version of Visual Studio shouldn't have anything to do with it. Are there already too many conditional formats? There can be a maximum of 3 for a range. If you exceed that Add will fail.

Comment: No, this was the only conditional format that is present for that worksheet. You said, my code worked for you. could you tell me which version of excel interop you used and the sample excel. I could cross check with that. Thx